# Where is refresh on my chrome OS PC

Tags: keyboard, dell-inspiron, google-chrome-os, chromebook, refresh

So I have installed chrome OS on my old dell laptop (Inspiron E1705), and in order to set it to developer mode i need to press ESC+F3+Refresh or something like that, now where is the refresh button/what is it on my DELL PC? Thanks a bunch! -Lucas, CO-CEO of EDG

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>F3</kbd>

Source: [Use your Chromebook keyboard](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/1047364?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

ChromeOS itself cannot be installed on 3rd party hardware so I think you mean you installed Neverware's CloudReady ChromeOS-based distro.

Here's a forum post on how to get root access which is roughly equivalent to developer mode on ChromeOS.

https://neverware.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206835307-Root-Administrator-password